# How to validate if client connection for Apache Pulsar is a valid one?

Tags: java, apache-pulsar

I have been creating a custom connector for Apache Pulsar in Mule. Once all the parameters for the Apache Pulsar client is set, how do we validate if the connection is successful without using any Consumer/Producer operation.

```
PulsarClient client = PulsarClient.builder().serviceUrl(pulsarConnectionParameter.getBootstrapServer()).build();
```

Comment: What do you mean with valid?

Comment: Valid means to check if we are successfully able to to connect to target Pulsar cluster with  the given Bootstrap Server url.